# How to check text content order in react Jest test cases?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using jest and react testing Library for writing test cases. I've called the element by id, now I need to check if the text content is having a certain order.

```
const getId = queryByAttribute.bind(null,'id');
const result = getById(component.container,'student-details-page');
```

Now result.textContent is Details:TeacherJin;SugaStudentDaphne
I need to check that Teacher always comes first followed by Student. It's actually values.i.e on UI it's

```
Details.  Teacher
          Jin
          Suga
        
          Student
          Daphne
```

How can I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Regex pattern to check if the word Teacher comes up before Student.

```
expect(result.textContent.match(/.*Teacher.*Student.*/)).not.toBeNull()
```